# How to address numeric overflows in Amazon Redshift

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have two measure columns in Redshift data:

Data Type of both columns is `Double Precision` with size 53

```
colA              colB
590437.223579   350213.276421
142069.091151   76554.205749
119372.370247   23001.207853
Null                Null
0                    0
678.345678           0
  0             24567.567866
```

I want do some operation like this:

```
sum(colA/(colA+ colB)) over (partition by some_other_col) as agg
```

It throws me divide by zero error.

So I did:

```
sum(cast(colA as decimal(3,2)) /nullif((cast(colA as decimal(3,2)) + cast (colB as decimal(3,2))),0)) over (partition by some_other_col) as agg
```

It again throws me error saying:

```
          InternalError_: Numeric data overflow (scale float to decimal)
        DETAIL:  
-----------------------------------------------
     error:  Numeric data overflow (scale float to decimal)
     code:      1058
     context:   64 bit overflow
     query:     3941320
   location:  numeric_bound.cpp:72
```

How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were getting "Divide by Zero" error because you didn't handled a denominator being zero.

Solution: Add **nullif**,

Well you did this BUT you also used "cast(...as decimal(3,2))" which gave you the "numeric overflow" error because you were casting raw values (larger than 9.99) to decimal(3,2) instead of casting your final value.

If you do however want your answer set to be a decimal(3,2), you can do this. But make sure that your actual answer is not larger than 9.99.

```
select cast(sum(colA /nullif((colA + colB),0)) over (partition by some_other_column) as decimal(3,2) ) as agg   
from table;
```

**Note:** For the sake of simplicity, I assumed your "some_other_column" value same for all rows.

Answer (score -1):

> It throws me divide by zero error.

Fix your original problem:

```
sum(colA/nullif(colA + colB, 0)) over (partition by some_other_col) as agg
```

This will ignore rows where `colA + colB` is 0.

Obviously, your floating point numbers won't fit in `decimal(3,2)`.  That only supports values from 0.00 to 9.99.

Comment: @Mac . . . You don't need to cast to solve a divide-by-zero problem.

Comment: Divide by problem has been taken care of but it didn't solve the problem ..after nullif i get InternalError_: Numeric data overflow (scale float to decimal) error